# How to set numbers of epoch in scikit-learn mlpregressor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, epoch

I'm trying to do some supervised learning using scikit-learn MLPRegressor. I want to know what is the leverage of numbers of epoch in supervised learning.

But when I set the MLP like this :

```
mlp = MLPRegressor(max_iter=100, learning_rate_init=0.1)
```

and then this :

```
mlp = MLPRegressor(max_iter=200, learning_rate_init=0.1)
```

and then this :

```
mlp = MLPRegressor(max_iter=500, learning_rate_init=0.1)
```

The prediction scores remain the same.
I don't know if it's correct or not for using max_iter to set the numbers of epoch, because prediction scores are constant although I change the numbers of max_iter.
But when I change the learning rate, the scores are change so there are some leverages of learning rate.

Anyone can help? thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using `max_iter` is indeed the correct way to limit the number of epochs. From the documentation of [`MLPRegressor`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html):

> **max_iter** : int, optional, default 200
>   Maximum number of iterations. The solver iterates until convergence (determined by ‘tol’) or this number of iterations. For stochastic solvers (‘sgd’, ‘adam’), note that this determines the number of epochs (how many times each data point will be used), not the number of gradient steps.

Note that their implementation has also a convergence check against the `tol` parameter, i.e., when the cost between two iterations changes less than `tol`, the learning will be stopped. `tol` is by default set to 0.0001 (10e-4) which may or may not be too much tolerance for your use case / training data.

In your case it seems that this precision is reached before even 100 iterations (`max_iter=100`).

Comment: thanks for the information. In my case, it isn't even change in 10, 20, 30 iterations. it remains the same as 100, 500, or 1000 iterations

Answer (score 1):

Roughly said, the number of epochs works as a leverage by enabling the optimizer to search longer for the optimal solution in the training set. But as stated by @fxx, the MLPRegressor implementation stops the number of epochs if the cost between two iterations doesn't change by less than `tol`. In your case, you could decrease `tol` parameter in order to force the algorithm to run longer.

And as an addition for the sake of a better performance of your implementation, you might check the `learning_rate` of your algorithm as well. 0.1 might be a little too much and hence the optimizer is likely to be overshooting.